# Can EJBQL Named Paremeters be Repeated in a Query?

Tags: java, jpa, ejbql

Just a quick one.  If I'm using an EJBQL query with named parameters, can I use the same parameter name twice in a single query to avoid having to set the value twice when I actually want to run the query?  For instance, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT g FROM Group g WHERE g = :group OR g.parent = :group
```

...so that doing:

```
query.setParameter("group", theGroup);
```

will populate both fields.  Is this possible?

I realize I could just run this and see, but I figured that asking first might save me (and anyone else who happens to find this question) a bit of time and frustration.

Comment: Works in Hibernate.  Don't know about other implementations.

Comment: Yep, it seems to work fine in Hibernate.  Do you think it would really be implementation-specific?

Comment: No, I don't think it would be implementation-specific.  But I haven't read the spec, and I don't want to give an answer that's wrong because of some other implementation that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's part of the spec. Makes no sense for a spec to insist on passing in an extra param name with dup value